# How do I change the backend in CoCalc to show a matplotlib scatter graph?

Tags: python, matplotlib, backend

I have a program that is working fine locally, but I need to use it in CoCalc on the cloud to share with a group. Everything works fine until the end, when I want to create a scatter graph, in standard way. There are a bunch of other specs, but essentially, it's just

```
plt.scatter(x, y, color = 'blue')
plt.show()
```

Nothing tricky. But in Cocalc, it tells me "UserWarning: Matplotlib is currently using agg, which is a non-GUI backend, so cannot show the figure."

Here are the imports from the beginning of the file:

```
import nltk
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
import numpy as np
```

I've searched for this error and tried the solutions I've found, such as importing tkinter. So, for instance, if I change the headers to

```
import nltk
import tkinter as tk
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('TkAgg')
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
import numpy as np
```

I get a different error: "Cannot load backend 'TkAgg' which requires the 'tk' interactive framework, as 'headless' is currently running."

I've seen instructions about pip installations and such, but a) I'm not sure the installations would make everything work for my group, and b) CoCalc generally has most of the standard packages ready to go, so maybe that's not the problem?

Obviously, I'm not experienced with these issues, so help is much appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried restarting your kernel? To restart the kernel you should click `Restart kernel` in the [kernel menu](https://doc.cocalc.com/howto/jupyter-kernel-selection.html#cocalc-s-jupyter-notebook). Get your original code and then run the cell where your code is. Make sure that you are not using `matplotlib.use(<matplotlib_backend>)` anywhere. If you still get the same error, try changing the kernel to another Python 3 option available

Comment: This sounds like an excellent idea, but I don't see the kernel menu. From the description you linked, it seems like that menu might be available only in the Jupyter environment? My document is just a Python file, and I can't find anything kernel-related to try.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using a Jupyter notebook in CoCalc, then the above will just work fine.  Here's an example:

https://cocalc.com/wstein/support/matplotlib-scatter-in-jupyter

If you're writing all of your code as part of a Python program (so, e.g., .py files) and running this from a Terminal, CoCalc will also fully support Tk and this working!  However, you have to start a new X11 desktop session in CoCalc by clicking +New --> "Linux Graphical X11 Desktop", then run your Python program from the terminal in the upper left.  You'll see any windows that pop up in the main window off to the right.

See https://cocalc.com/wstein/support/scatter-matplotlib-x11

[image]